# Prove conditional expectation $E(A|X=x)$

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

We already know that $P(A|X=x)=\frac{P[A I \{X=x\}]}{P(X=x)}$,

but how to prove $E(A|X=x)=\frac{E[A  I \{X=x\}]}{P(X=x)}$？

In other words, can I say $E(A|B)=\frac{E[A B]}{E(B)}$?

Comment: As far as $E[A]$ is concerned, $A$ is a random variable, not set, but what does $A\cap B$ mean?

Comment: @gunes Thanks! Have edited.

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable so $E(X|B)=\frac{E(X1_B)}{P(B)}.$